# Java web application Paypal IPN

Tags: java, web-applications, paypal, paypal-ipn

I created my own website with Java Servlet and JSP.

I integrated Paypal payments with the normal buttons. I want to do some actions on a database when a user completes the payment.

I think I have to create the *IPN listener servlet*, but I can't find anything useful.

Comment: It's all documented at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/

Comment: there aren't any information about java. My problem is that I have the change some value into a db if the payment is completed.

Comment: As above, the developer docs contains information on your options - [see the section referencing `PDT` and `IPN` **here**](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/wp_standard_overview/?mark=pdt%20ipn) as possible options where you can obtain transaction information from Paypal and perform whatever "backend" process you need to do.

Comment: Yea, thanks for the link but there are some example for asp, php and so but no one for java. I need something for java

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved my problem.
I created a servlet IPN using an example for a maven project. (https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-java)
Simply I added this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.paypal.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>paypal-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

And then I created the servlet ipn with this code in doPost

```
    Map<String,String> configMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
    configMap.put("mode", "sandbox");
    IPNMessage ipnlistener = new IPNMessage(request,configMap);

    boolean isIpnVerified = ipnlistener.validate();
    String transactionType = ipnlistener.getTransactionType();
    Map<String,String> map = ipnlistener.getIpnMap();
```